# Что после компиляции попадает в апк из подключенного движка?

Tags: java, android

Вот говорят,  что если реализация физики в игре простая, то лучше не подключать движок,  да бы не захламлять проект.  Я например в адроид студио к проекту подключаю движок    AndEngine . И например использовал пару классов,  выходит при компиляции в апк в итоге попадут все классы библиотеки? Даже те которые я не использовал?  Почему студия не может скомпилировать только использованные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию - да, все классы из всех зависимостей будут скомпилированы и упакованы в apk файл. Да, некоторые из них могут быть незадействованы вовсе и всё равно попадут в итоговый файл.

Для решения этой проблемы вы можете использовать proguard - он удалит весь неиспользуемый код и ресурсы. Вот ссылка на доки: [тык](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

Вот ещё несколько устаревший, но неплохой пример настройки proguard для андроида: [тык](https://gist.github.com/Jackgris/c4a71328b1ae346cba04)

Comment: Спасибо, я просто хотел узнать, что да как. Пока мне хотя бы написать , что нибудь, а потом возиться с размером и производительностью. Еще вот вопрос, это программа которая неиспользуемый код удаляет, она работает точно или примерно удаляет что не нужно ? будет ли код чище , если самому вручную из движка использовать всё что нужно , не подключая движок?

Comment: Проще просто взять и подключить движок не задумываясь вовсе о размере установочного файла из-за него. Удалять она должна точно - лишнего не останется. Препарировать движки не стоит - зачем оно вам?